# Uipageview with separate lists

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, xcode6, uipageviewcontroller

I am writing an app in xCode 6.2 using storyboards and there is a need to present 2 different lists within a page view type setup (similar to Beat - Music Player).

The PageView controller is something I have never used before, so, I have looked at several examples and all deal with an Image View and changing the content of that based on an array. Whereas, what I am essentially trying to achieve is two separate ViewControllers being swiped between using the PageView controller. Is this even possible? If so, would anybody be able to point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the magic does by the two delegate methods `viewControllerBeforeViewController` and `viewControllerAfterViewController` ...

when you load the first viewcontroller to your pageviewcontroller with `setViewControllers:@[theFirstViewController]` the pageviewcontroller will ask the two delegates for the next and the previous vcs... you are responsible that the delegates returns the vcs you want to display, no matter what kind of vc you want to display...

Comment: Thanks! Simple when you know how.